# 403 Forbidden during setExpressCheckout

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am getting the following error during `Expresscheckout` in sandbox account using `setExpressCheckout` method. I am using `SOAP` library `paypal_base.jar`, `paypal_stubs.jar`

```
PM com.paypal.sdk.exceptions.TransactionException <init>
SEVERE: (403)Forbidden
```

Anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

please refer to to https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/event_details?eventId=4283.
 You can try to use "org.apache.axis.transport.http.CommonsHTTPSender" in axis to support http1.1. You have to use axis 1.3 or more as 1.2 has bug with https connection

Comment: already using axis1.4 but i am getting same error , and also tried with axis 1.3  can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

add a client-config.wsdd to your classpath to use http1.1. You can set log4j to debug level to see if you are useing http 1.0 now. If not, this will not help you.
Content of file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deployment name="defaultClientConfig"
            xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/"
            xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">
    <transport name="http" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.CommonsHTTPSender">
        <parameter name="PROTOCOL">HTTP/1.1</parameter>
    </transport>
    <transport name="local" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.local.LocalSender"/>
    <transport name="java" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.java.JavaSender"/>
</deployment>
```

Comment: i am getting following error at com.senthil.SetExpressCheckoutService.main(SetExpressCheckoutService.java:35)
Caused by: (403)Forbidden
 at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:744)
 at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
 at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)

Comment: I want to do this, but can someone explain me how to "include it in classpath" ?

Answer (score 1):

This is like a summery of all answers above along with additional reference.

As mentioned by user3405529 follow the link and understand your problem.

**Merchants using the HTTP 1.0 protocol.**

This is common for all who are using old PayPal API with axis 1.4

This is the problem in my project.

I referred this link for more details to understand and solve the problem

http://marc.info/?l=axis-user&m=119144869612056

There are four ways to solve this

1)Modify axis source code to use HTTP 1.1 protocol

```
    String httpver = msgContext.getStrProp(MessageContext.HTTP_TRANSPORT_VERSION);
    if (null == httpver) {
         httpver = HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_V11;
    }
    //httpver = httpver.trim();
    //if (httpver.equals(HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_V11)) {
    //   http10 = false;
    //}
```

OR
 Set Message Context msgContext.setStrProp(..) as HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_V11

Then rebuild axis and maintain your own source code for reference

2)As per user3405529 use client-config.wsdd in classpath with
    java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.CommonsHTTPSender in transport
    tag

I tested with this changes and it is working as expected.

But both the approaches use HTTP 1.1 by default. In our project as we are not prepared for this change of HTTP protocol version.

see more details at http://www2.research.att.com/~bala/papers/h0vh1.html

3)Update the PayPal stub and rebuild it for use - I do not try it.

4)Update the PayPal SDK to latest version...

We go with updated PayPal SDK. It will be helpful in future.

I hope it is helpful