# Why do I get Caused by: com.paypal.sdk.exceptions.TransactionException: (403)Forbidden

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Why do I get this error when calling pyapal api in sandbox environment?
I don't know how to start debugging this problem.
Thanks.

Here is part of stacktrace"
Caused by: com.paypal.sdk.exceptions.TransactionException: (403)Forbidden
    at com.paypal.sdk.core.soap.SOAPAPICaller.callSOAP(SOAPAPICaller.java:473)
....
Caused by: (403)Forbidden
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:744)

Answer (score 0):

I found a post with the exact same error message that you are receiving:

[Stack Error Message 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295967/403-forbidden-during-setexpresscheckout)

There are two answers that give a detailed explanation as to why this error message is being received and how to resolve it.

This is a standard HTTP error. Here is a link to the PayPal documentation just in case you need it:
[PayPal Developer API Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/)